# Of (verb), of (verb), and of (verb)?

Tags: nouns, prepositions, conjunctions

Which is correct?

Example 1: We want to emphasize the importance of running, swimming, and dancing.

Example 2: We want to emphasize the importance of running, of swimming, and of dancing.

Comment: They're both correct, but the first is better stylistically (tighter; not as clunky).

Answer (score 1):

The  first sentence is better as we traditionally use one linking word /here: preposition/ with homogeneous parts  of the sentence.
The second sentence is acceptable, but it sounds rather formal.